# How to disable the Hypersistence banner when using hibernate-types-52 in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-types

I use the `com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52` dependency in my Spring Boot Project. And, I notice that on application boot, some large log messages were added:

```
2020-04-09 11:43:59.535  WARN 3465 --- [           main] Hypersistence Optimizer                  : You should use Hypersistence Optimizer to speed up your Hibernate application!
2020-04-09 11:43:59.535  WARN 3465 --- [           main] Hypersistence Optimizer                  : For more details, go to https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/
2020-04-09 11:43:59.536  INFO 3465 --- [           main] Hypersistence Optimizer                  : 
 _    _                           _     _
| |  | |                         (_)   | |
| |__| |_   _ _ __   ___ _ __ ___ _ ___| |_ ___ _ __   ___ ___
|  __  | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '__/ __| / __| __/ _ \ '_ \ / __/ _ \
| |  | | |_| | |_) |  __/ |  \__ \ \__ \ ||  __/ | | | (_|  __/
|_|  |_|\__, | .__/ \___|_|  |___/_|___/\__\___|_| |_|\___\___|
         __/ | |
        |___/|_|

           ____        _   _           _
          / __ \      | | (_)         (_)
         | |  | |_ __ | |_ _ _ __ ___  _ _______ _ __
         | |  | | '_ \| __| | '_ ` _ \| |_  / _ \ '__|
         | |__| | |_) | |_| | | | | | | |/ /  __/ |
          \____/| .__/ \__|_|_| |_| |_|_/___\___|_|
                | |
                |_|
```

The hint is nice and the project sounds actually interesting, but still want to have the banner removed from my application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a description by the Project Owner why the banner was introduced, why it will not be disabled on default and how to disable it manually.

[How to remove the Hibernate Types banner](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/issues/196)

### The automatic banner removal mode

In short, you can buy a [Hypersistence Optimizer license](https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/) and add the project as a dependency to benefit from the JPA and Hibernate auto-tuning checks.

### Manual banner removal

Or you can add either a `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate-types.properties` file to your project with the one property to disable the banner:

```
hibernate.types.print.banner = false
```

Or, you could pass this property as a Java System property:

```
java -Dhibernate.types.print.banner=false -jar target/high-performance-java-persistence-1.0.0.jar
```

### Spring Boot

Starting with the release of Hibernate 5.5 and the `hibernate-types-55` dependency, you can now provide the `hibernate.types.print.banner` property in your `application.properties` file, like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.types.print.banner=false
```

> If you're using `hibernate-types-52` or older dependencies, then you won't be able to provide this setting via the Spring Boot `application.properties` file.

Comment: Not sure why but adding this property didn't remove the banner for me.

Comment: maybe the file is not part of your class path.

Comment: @AnkitBhatia If you're using Spring Boot, check out the Spring Boot section I added to the answer.

Comment: @AnkitBhatia please check my answer below, this might help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118423/how-to-disable-the-hypersistence-optimizer-banner-when-using-hibernate-types-5#answer-64692998

Comment: @VladMihalcea i am unable to turn off the banner via the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.types.print.banner=false, even though i am using hibernate-types-55:2.12.0. any idea why? (i can turn it off by creating the hibernate.properties file)

Comment: @ksemeks Add a breakpoint at [this line](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/e76241a3091078713dd4b57de085f5fadce5e0db/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/TypeFactory.java#L97) in Hibernate ORM and see why the `TypeBootstrapContext` object is not passed to the Hibernate Types constructor.

Comment: Looks like the issue behind the link has been deleted, and it's not in the archive.org Wayback Machine: [How to remove the Hibernate Types banner](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/issues/196).

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to the answers above, if you do not have access to JVM arguments.

Both these approaches work with Spring Boot, tested on 2.2.x.

## Option 1: additional properties file

Create a file at `src/main/resources/hibernate-types.properties`.

```
hibernate.types.print.banner=false
```

## Option 2: hacking around the hibernate-types check

Create either of the following files (depending on your version of `hibernate-types`).

Latest way of doing things: `src/main/java/io/hypersistence/optimizer/core/License.java`.

```
package io.hypersistence.optimizer.core;

public class License {
  public static class Signature {
  }
}
```

An older version checks for `src/main/java/io/hypersistence/optimizer/HypersistenceOptimizer.java`.

```
package io.hypersistence.optimizer;

public class HypersistenceOptimizer {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the logger name and the level to `WARN` or `ERROR` in the log configuration file.

Example for **log4j2** (`log4j2.yml`):

```yaml
configuration:
  Loggers:
    Logger:
      - name: Hibernate Types
        level: WARN
```

**Note**: Logger's name is important here: `Hibernate Types`. Tested for `hibernate-types-52:2.9.13`. The same can be achieved for other versions, just include the proper logger name. One can find the logger name in the logs.

[image]

Comment: The banner is printed at WARN level, probably best not to turn it off.